# How to make a window that's full screen but still shows the task bar

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'd like to make a captionless window that covers the entire desktop, but still shows the task bar. What is the best way to do this?

I can detect where the taskbar is and just resize my window to exclude it, but then I need to know when the user changes the size / position of the task bar.

Or, is there a combination of window styles or something else that will make sure my window is always behind the task bar?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cant just maximise your window?

Comment: Respond to WM_GETMINMAXINFO and carefully calculate the positions so that the window caption and border exactly fall outside of the monitor area and get overlapped by the taskbar.  There's no general case that this works well on multiple monitors, they don't have to have the same size and only one of them shows the taskbar.

Comment: Windows automatically puts the task bar behind windows with a caption (not sure the exact criteria at the moment, but WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW). There is a maximum window size so we cannot create a window with caption and just offset it so the caption / borders don't show. My current thinking is to go ahead with WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, but handle WM_NCCALCSIZE so the caption / etc are nonexistent. Trying now.

Answer (score 3):

Set your window placement using the return value from [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing SPI_GETWORKAREA as a parameter.

> Retrieves the size of the work area on the primary display monitor.
>   The work area is the portion of the screen not obscured by the system
>   taskbar or by application desktop toolbars. The pvParam parameter must
>   point to a RECT structure that receives the coordinates of the work
>   area, expressed in virtual screen coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Maximise a window with no caption/border.

Comment: Unfortunately that will only cover one monitor then, not the whole desktop. Wish it could work though - elegant idea.

Comment: Other than the minor detail that you can't remove the border and caption from a window without re-creating it.  Well, it isn't minor.

Comment: If you want the window to cover multiple monitors, then you're sunk, aren't you? The desktop is not in general rectangular, with or without the task bar.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept it by ticking the green tick mark to the left. If it doesn't, please ask for clarifiaction or expand your question. Thanks.